# Spring Batch restart crashed jobs

Tags: crash, spring-batch, recover

Hi spring batch users,

regarding the documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/htmlsingle/#d5e1320

"If the process died ("kill -9" or server failure) the job is, of course, not running, but the JobRepository has no way of knowing because no-one told it before the process died."

I try to find and restart the stale job executions by using

```
Set<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName);
...
jobExecution.setStatus(FAILED);
jobExecution.setEndTime(new Date());
jobRepository.update(jobExecution);
jobOperator.restart(jobExecution.getId());
```

But this seems to be very inconvenient.
1) I have to do this before other (new) jobs could be started.
2) I have to handle multiple instances of running servers so findRunningJobExecutions will not do the trick.

You can find other questions regarding this topic:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2433?jql=project%20%3D%20BATCH%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Open%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC
[Spring Batch after JVM crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461040/spring-batch-after-jvm-crash)

I would love to see a solution to register a "start up clean jobs listener". This will still not fix the problems originated by the multi server environment because spring batch does not know if the JobExecution marked by STARTED is not running on an other instance.

Thanks for any advice
Alex

Comment: kill -9 is a scenario where a real (and clean) re-start is not possible, spring batch was not able to save the current process progress to re-start on it

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your comment. I know it is not designed that way but it should handle that stuff. I created an issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2505?filter=-2  It may not be very common to crash the server like that but it is possible for a production environment and should be handled in the most clean way.

Answer (score 0):

Your job cannot and should not recover "automatically" from a `kill -9` scenario. A `kill -9` is treated very differently than you application throwing a caught `Exception`. The reason for this is that you've effectively pulled the carpet out from under the application without giving it a chance to reach a synchronization point with the database to commit any necessary information to the `ExecutionContext` or update the job/step status(es). Therefore, the last status touchpoint with the database will remain and the job will still look `STARTED`.

"OK, fine" you say, "but if I start another execution, I want it to find that `STARTED` execution, and pick up where it left off." The problem here is that there is no clean way for the application to distinguish a job that is ACTUALLY RUNNING from one that has failed but couldn't up the database. The framework here correctly errs on the side of caution and prevents you from starting a job that already appears running, and this is a GOOD thing.

Why? Because let's assume your job was actually still running and you restarted by accident. As coded, the framework will start to spin up, see your running execution and fail with the following message `A job execution for this job is already running`. I can't tell you how many times we've been saved by this because someone accidentally launched a job twice!

If you were to implement the listener you suggest, the 2nd execution would instead be allowed to start and you'd have 2 different JVMs repeating the same work, possibly writing to the same files/tables and causing a huge data mess that could be impossible to clean up.

Trust me, in the event the Linux terminal kills your job or your job dies because the connection to the database has been severed, you WANT human eyes on those execution states before you attempt a restart.

Finally, on the off chance you actually wanted to kill you job, you can leverage several other standard patterns for stopping jobs:

[*Stop via throw Exception*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html#stoppingAJobManuallyForBusinessReasons)

[*Stop via `JobOperator.stop()`*](https://according2albert.wordpress.com/2015/03/29/graceful-shutdown-stopping-spring-batch-job-executions/)

Comment: This is actually not true. We run production environments where recovery from an OS failure (think hardware died, power outage) is vital.

Comment: Meant to add: Of course, your specific job needs to be able to repeat (possibly in steps) transactionally. We use Quartz job recovery for that.

Comment: Sure, if you want to create an ad-hoc "Mark As Failed" job to update job and step executions from STARTED/STARTING to FAILED, and you only run that job once the OS is back up and running (and before any other Spring Batch applications have been kicked off), I think that would be fine. However, you could accomplish the same thing with batch updates to `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` and `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION`.

Comment: I dont think that's how it's done. The specific scheduler instance is checking for started and never finished jobs. So the specific "node" needs to be up again to recover its jobs. Which is reasonable as you would expect the node to be restarted. The actual job implementation needs to be aware of whether it has completed its work previously or not and what to do to complete work now - which is not hard in a transactional environment.

Comment: The framework would prevent those jobs from restarting until the status had been updated to Failed.